# Criar tabuleiro dinamicamente

Tags: java, rmi

Estou resolvendo um problema utilizando RMI de uma batalha naval, estou precisando gerar o tabuleiro dinamicamente de acordo com a necessidade do usuario, este codigo peguei de um video e estou adaptando conforme se pede no exercicio.

```
public class Jogador {

TocadorSom tsom = new TocadorSom();

public Jogador(int cod) throws RemoteException {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Informe o tamanho do tabuleiro \nQuantidade de linhas: ");
    int linhas = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("quantidade de colunas: ");
    int colunas = sc.nextInt();
    int[][] tabuleiro = new int[10][10];
    int[][] navios = new int[3][2];
    int[] tiro = new int[2];
    boolean vez = false;
    int tentativas = 0, acertos = 0;
    MsImpl ms = new MsImpl();

    tsom.play("Inicio");

    try {

        Ms c = (Ms) Naming.lookup("rmi://127.0.0.1:1090/batalhaNaval");
        System.out.println();
        inicializarNavios(navios);
        inicializarTabuleiro(tabuleiro, 10, 10);
        System.out.println("");

        do {
            mostrarTabuleiro(tabuleiro, 10, 10);
            darTiro(tiro);
            tentativas++;

            if (ms.acertou(tiro, navios)) {
                acertos++;
            } else {
                dica(tiro, navios, tentativas);

            }
            alteraTabuleiro(tiro, navios, tabuleiro);

        } while (acertos != 3);

        if (acertos == 3) {
            mostrarTabuleiro(tabuleiro, 10, 10);
            System.out.println("Vencedor jogador: " + ms.vez(cod));
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }

}

public static void inicializarTabuleiro(int[][] tabuleiro, int l, int c) {
    for (int linha = 0; linha < 10; linha++) {
        for (int coluna = 0; coluna < 10; coluna++) {
            tabuleiro[linha][coluna] = -1;
        }
    }
}

public static void mostrarTabuleiro(int[][] tabuleiro, int l, int c) {

    for (int i = 1; i <= l; i++) {
        System.out.print("\t" + i);
    }
    System.out.println();

    for (int linha = 0; linha < l; linha++) {
        System.out.print((linha + 1) + "");
        for (int coluna = 0; coluna < c; coluna++) {

            if (tabuleiro[linha][coluna] == -1) {
                System.out.print("\t" + "~");
            } else if (tabuleiro[linha][coluna] == 0) {
                System.out.print("\t" + "*");
            } else if (tabuleiro[linha][coluna] == 1) {
                System.out.print("\t" + "x");
            }

        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}

public static void inicializarNavios(int[][] navios) {

    Random sorteio = new Random();

    for (int c = 0; c < 3; c++) {
        navios[c][0] = sorteio.nextInt(5);
        navios[c][1] = sorteio.nextInt(5);

        for (int i = 0; i < c; i++) {
            if ((navios[c][0] == navios[i][0]) && (navios[c][1] == navios[i][1])) {

                do {

                    navios[c][0] = sorteio.nextInt();
                    navios[c][1] = sorteio.nextInt();
                } while ((navios[c][0] == navios[i][0]) && (navios[c][1] == navios[i][1]));
            }
        }
    }

}

public static void darTiro(int[] tiro) {

    Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Linha: ");
    tiro[0] = entrada.nextInt();
    tiro[0]--;

    System.out.print("Coluna: ");
    tiro[1] = entrada.nextInt();
    tiro[1]--;

    TocadorSom tsomTiro = new TocadorSom();

    tsomTiro.play("explosao");

}

public static void dica(int[] tiro, int[][] navios, int tentativas) {

    int linha = 0, coluna = 0;

    for (int c = 0; c < navios.length; c++) {
        if (navios[c][0] == tiro[0]) {
            linha++;
        }
        if (navios[c][1] == tiro[1]) {
            coluna++;
        }

    }

    System.out.print("\nDica " + tentativas + "\nLinha " + (tiro[0] + 1) + " -> navios " + linha + "\nColuna "
            + (tiro[1] + 1) + " -> navios " + coluna + "\n\n");

}

public static void alteraTabuleiro(int[] tiro, int[][] navios, int[][] tabuleiro) throws RemoteException {

    MsImpl ms = new MsImpl();

    if (ms.acertou(tiro, navios)) {
        tabuleiro[tiro[0]][tiro[1]] = 1;
    } else {
        tabuleiro[tiro[0]][tiro[1]] = 0;
    }
}
}
```

Ao invés de ser [10][10], gostaria de implementar de acordo com a entrada do usuário.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supondo que `linhas` e `colunas` sejam as entradas de usuario que quer aplicar ao array:

```
int[][] tabuleiro = new int[linhas][colunas];
```

E na inicialização dos métodos:

```
...

inicializarTabuleiro(tabuleiro, linhas, colunas);

...

mostrarTabuleiro(tabuleiro, linhas, colunas);

...
```

Comment: mas o metodo inicializarTabuleiro nao tem esse vetor, ele nao reconhece dentro dos laços as variaveis linhas e colunas.

Comment: @CarlosDiego É só você passar os mesmos dados pra esse método, não tem segredo.

Comment: Deu certo @Articuno

Comment: vc pode me ajudar nessa??
 https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/248773/adicionar-embarca%C3%A7oes-dinamicamente-no-tabuleiro