# Adicionar embarcações dinamicamente no tabuleiro

Tags: java, rmi

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicaçao utilizando RMI que simula o jogo da batalha naval. Meu codigo por enquanto esta gerando dinamicamente o tabuleiro e posicionando automaticamente os navios no tabuleiro, minha duvida é como faço para escolher onde adicionar cada tipo de embarcaçao (destroyer, cruzador, hidro-aviao, porta-aviao e submarino) no meu tabuleiro?
*Obs: preciso diferenciar cada tipo de embarcaçao no tabuleiro, de acordo com a imagem:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Lado cliente:

```
public class Jogador {

TocadorSom tsom = new TocadorSom();
TocadorSom tsomTiro = new TocadorSom();
TocadorSom tsomacertou = new TocadorSom();

public Jogador(int cod) throws RemoteException {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Informe o tamanho do tabuleiro \nQuantidade de linhas: ");
    int linhas = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("quantidade de colunas: ");
    int colunas = sc.nextInt();
    int[][] tabuleiro = new int[linhas][colunas];
    int[][] navios = new int[5][2];
    int[] tiro = new int[2];
    boolean vez = false;
    int tentativas = 0, acertos = 0;
    MsImpl ms = new MsImpl();

    tsom.play("intro");

    try {

        Ms c = (Ms) Naming.lookup("rmi://127.0.0.1:1090/batalhaNaval");
        System.out.println();
        inicializarNavios(navios);
        inicializarTabuleiro(tabuleiro, linhas, colunas);
        System.out.println("");

        do {
            mostrarTabuleiro(tabuleiro, linhas, colunas);
            darTiro(tiro);
            tentativas++;

            if (ms.acertou(tiro, navios)) {
                tsomacertou.play("acertou");
                acertos++;

            } else {
                dica(tiro, navios, tentativas);
                tsomTiro.play("agua");

            }
            alteraTabuleiro(tiro, navios, tabuleiro);

        } while (acertos != 5);

        if (acertos == 5) {
            mostrarTabuleiro(tabuleiro, linhas, colunas);
            System.out.println("Vencedor jogador: " + ms.vez(cod));
            tsomTiro.play("win");
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }

}

public static void inicializarTabuleiro(int[][] tabuleiro, int linhas, int colunas) {

    for (int linha = 0; linha < linhas; linha++) {
        for (int coluna = 0; coluna < colunas; coluna++) {
            tabuleiro[linha][coluna] = -1;
        }
    }
}

public static void mostrarTabuleiro(int[][] tabuleiro, int linhas, int colunas) {

    for (int i = 1; i <= linhas; i++) {
        System.out.print("\t" + i);
    }
    System.out.println();

    for (int linha = 0; linha < linhas; linha++) {
        System.out.print((linha + 1) + "");
        for (int coluna = 0; coluna < colunas; coluna++) {

            if (tabuleiro[linha][coluna] == -1) {
                System.out.print("\t" + "~");
            } else if (tabuleiro[linha][coluna] == 0) {
                System.out.print("\t" + "*");
            } else if (tabuleiro[linha][coluna] == 1) {
                System.out.print("\t" + "x");
            }

        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}

public static void inicializarNavios(int[][] navios) {

    public static void inicializarNavios(int[][] navios) {

    for (int c = 0; c < 4; c++) {
        System.out.println("Informe onde deseja colocar o destroyer - \nLinha: ");
        navios[c][0] = entrada.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Coluna: ");
        navios[c][1] = entrada.nextInt();
        System.out.println(c);
    }
    for (int c = 4; c < 9; c++) {
        System.out.println("Informe onde deseja colocar o porta-aviao - \nLinha: ");
        navios[c][0] = entrada.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Coluna: ");
        navios[c][1] = entrada.nextInt();
        System.out.println(c);
    }
    for (int c = 9; c < 12; c++) {
        System.out.println("Informe onde deseja colocar o hidro-aviao - \nLinha: ");
        navios[c][0] = entrada.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Coluna: ");
        navios[c][1] = entrada.nextInt();
        System.out.println(c);
    }
    for (int c = 12; c < 15; c++) {
        System.out.println("Informe onde deseja colocar o cruzador - \nLinha: ");
        navios[c][0] = entrada.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Coluna: ");
        navios[c][1] = entrada.nextInt();
        System.out.println(c);
    }int c = 16;
    System.out.println("Informe onde deseja colocar o submarino - \nLinha: ");
    navios[c][0] = entrada.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Coluna: ");
    navios[c][1] = entrada.nextInt();
    System.out.println(c);
}       }

}

public static void darTiro(int[] tiro) {

    Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Linha: ");
    tiro[0] = entrada.nextInt();
    tiro[0]--;

    System.out.print("Coluna: ");
    tiro[1] = entrada.nextInt();
    tiro[1]--;
}

public static void dica(int[] tiro, int[][] navios, int tentativas) {

    int linha = 0, coluna = 0;

    for (int c = 0; c < navios.length; c++) {
        if (navios[c][0] == tiro[0]) {
            linha++;
        }
        if (navios[c][1] == tiro[1]) {
            coluna++;
        }
    }

    System.out.print("\nLinha " + (tiro[0] + 1) + " -> navios " + linha + "\nColuna "
            + (tiro[1] + 1) + " -> navios " + coluna + "\n\n");

}

public static void alteraTabuleiro(int[] tiro, int[][] navios, int[][] tabuleiro) throws RemoteException {

    MsImpl ms = new MsImpl();

    if (ms.acertou(tiro, navios)) {
        tabuleiro[tiro[0]][tiro[1]] = 1;
    } else {
        tabuleiro[tiro[0]][tiro[1]] = 0;
    }
}
}
```

Lado cliente:

```
 package Cliente;

 import java.rmi.RemoteException;

 public class J1 {

public static void main(String[] args) throws RemoteException {
    Jogador j1 = new Jogador(1);
}
}
```

Lado cliente:

```
package Cliente;

import java.rmi.RemoteException;

public class J2 {

public static void main(String[] args) throws RemoteException {
    Jogador j2 = new Jogador(2);
}
}
```

Interface

```
package Interface;

import java.rmi.Remote;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;

 public interface BatalhaNaval extends Remote {

public boolean acertou(int[] tiro, int[][] navios) throws RemoteException;

public int jogou(String nome) throws RemoteException;

public boolean vez(int cod) throws RemoteException;
}
```

Servidor:

```
package Servidor;

import Interface.BatalhaNaval;
import implementacao.ServidorImpl;
import java.rmi.Naming;

public class Servidor {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry.createRegistry(1090);
        BatalhaNaval c = new ServidorImpl();
        Naming.rebind("rmi://127.0.0.1:1090/batalhaNaval", c);

        System.out.println("\nSevidor conectado!!");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
}
```

Implementação

```
package implementacao;

import Interface.BatalhaNaval;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject;

public class ServidorImpl extends UnicastRemoteObject implements BatalhaNaval {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
public static boolean j2 = false;
public static boolean j1 = true;

public ServidorImpl() throws RemoteException {

}

@Override
public boolean acertou(int[] tiro, int[][] navios) throws RemoteException {

    for (int c = 0; c < navios.length; c++) {
        if (tiro[0] == navios[c][0] && tiro[1] == navios[c][1]) {
            System.out.println("Você acertou o tiro (" + (tiro[0] + 1) + " , " + (tiro[1] + 1) + ")");
            return true;
        }
    }System.out.println("Você errou o tiro (" + (tiro[0] + 1) + " , " + (tiro[1] + 1) + ")");
    return false;
}

@Override
public int jogou(String nome) throws RemoteException {

    if (nome.equals("Jogador1")) {
        return 1;
    }
    if (nome.equals("Jogador2")) {
        return 2;
    }
    return 0;
}

@Override
public boolean vez(int cod) throws RemoteException {

    if (cod == 1) {
        return j1;
    } else if (cod == 2) {
        return j2;
    }
    return false;
}
}
```

Comment: Por favor, forneça um [mcve] para que assim seja possivel executar o código e testar o problema, para propor uma solução.

Comment: Pronto @Articuno